# jquery how to get an attribute from an array and pass it to another array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have 2 div containers with some inner div's. 
What I would like to achieve is placing the 'rel' attribute as a background image on the thumbs...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" rel="image_01"></div>
    <div class="item" rel="image_02"></div>
    <div class="item" rel="image_03"></div>
...
<div>

<div class="thumbs">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve this by making two arrays

```
var visuals = $('.container .item');
var visualArr = $.makeArray(visuals);

var thumbs =  $('.thumbs .thumb');
var thumbArr = $.makeArray(thumbs);
```

then a loop for placing this on every thumb:

```
for (var i =0; i<visualArr.length; i++){
    thumbArr[i].css('background','url("'+visualArr[i].attr('rel')+'")');
}
```

But that's not working, probably I make it myself to difficult, ... again :)
Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just simply do it this way

```
$('.item').each(function(i) {  // take the index to be used
    $('.thumbs .thumb').eq(i).css("background", 'url("' + $(this).attr("rel") + '")');
});
```

Comment: @saerts glad it helped. Don't forget to mark it as the answer by clicking the tick mark if it helped.

Comment: @saerts well you found it and that's great :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is not working is you don't have a jquery reference so .css is undefined.

```
a = $('.thumbs .thumb');
a = [<div class="thumb"></div>,<div class="thumb"></div>,<div class="thumb"></div>]
```

A is a jquery obj, but if you get inside it, ie a[0] you get a js reference

you need to select that item

```
$(a[0])
```

and then you can access those methods.